# how to synchronize this lock across thread in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, locking

I have the following code:

```
    private static async Task SaveAsync()
    {
        if (Monitor.TryEnter(_SaveLock, 1000))
        {
            try
            {
                Logging.Info(" writing bitmex data to database");
                await SomelenghthyDbUpdate1.ConfigureAwait(false);
                await SomelenghthyDbUpdate2.ConfigureAwait(false);
                await SomelenghthyDbUpdate3.ConfigureAwait(false);
                await SomelenghthyDbUpdate4.ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            finally
            {
                Monitor.Exit(_SaveLock);
            }
        }
    }
```

First, ConfigureAwait false vs true does yield a real speed difference.
So, knowing that the finally part can be executed in another thread than the caller there is an issue when releasing the lock.

I am trying to prevent two save operations to happen at the same time, since they're event driven AND can be skipped if needed as they happen periodically.

another option I was thinking about is to make an array of tasks and, in the caller thread do a Task.WaitAll(tasks). In that scenario, is it guaranteed I would still be on the same thread at exit?

But is there a clean solution to this problem? maybe setting a flag through a lock?

Comment: Have you considered [SemaphoreSlim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim?view=netframework-4.8) instead of Monitor?

Comment: I haven't; can I release the semaphore from a different thread?

Comment: Yes, you can. Docs: _"The SemaphoreSlim class doesn't enforce thread or task identity on calls to the Wait, WaitAsync, and Release methods."_

Comment: just tried and it worked perfectly! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim.waitasync?view=netframework-4.8) *"The SemaphoreSlim class doesn't enforce thread or task identity on calls to the Wait, WaitAsync, and Release methods."*

```
private static SemaphoreSlim sem = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

private static async Task SaveAsync()
{
   if(await sem.WaitAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))) // Can be pimped with cancel token
   {
        try
        {
            Logging.Info(" writing bitmex data to database");
            await SomelenghthyDbUpdate1.ConfigureAwait(false);
            await SomelenghthyDbUpdate2.ConfigureAwait(false);
            await SomelenghthyDbUpdate3.ConfigureAwait(false);
            await SomelenghthyDbUpdate4.ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        finally
        {
            sem.Release();
        }
    }
}
```